# Include a helm template in yaml file, removing quotes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, podspec

This is a snippet from `helpers.tpl` of my helm chart:

```
{{/*
Pod-specific labels - added to pod template only
Adding a revision label to the pod will cause it to restart every time the chart is deployed.
*/}}
{{- define "app.podLabels" -}}
helm-revision: {{ .Release.Revision | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

Including it in pod labels like this:

```
  labels:
    {{- include "app.podLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
```

The result would be as shown below. The quotes around `1` is required because Kubernetes accepts string labels only.

```
  labels:
    helm-revision: "1"
```

I need to use the same template for an init container, replacing the `:` with `=` like this:

```
  args:
    - "pod"
    - "-l {{ include "app.podLabels" . | replace ": " "=" }}"
```

But the output would be an incorrect yaml:

```
  args:
    - "pod"
    - "-l helm-revision="1""
```

with error:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 34: did not find expected '-' indicator
```

What I actually want is something like this, that doesn't contain quotes around `1`:

```
  args:
    - "pod"
    - "-l helm-revision=1"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by replacing `"` with nothing ( In effect, removes `"`). Escaping the quotes using `\` character would be needed.

Also adding a `replace` function to remove newlines and add `,`  as a separator between labels. This would be helpful if more than one pod-specific label is present. But make sure this will work in your case when rendering the template.

```
      args:
        - "pod"
        - "-l {{ include "app.podLabels" . | replace ": " "=" | replace "\n" ", " | replace "\"" "" }}"
```